# WPML plugin redirect

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I'm using WPML plugin for language switcher in my web site. I have two language EN and DE, I want to open web site based on browser language. But, if browser is in FR or IT languages, I want to open website in EN (means that for other languages that aren't in DE, web should open in EN). Note: Default language of WPML should be DE.

Code that I have used, but doesn't work (or take too much time) is:

```
$lc = ""; // Initialize the language code variable
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
$lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
}

if($lc == "de"){
header("location: /de");
exit();
} 
else {
header("location: /en");
exit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

WPML Plugin, There is giving the option for open website based on browser language.

To enable browser language redirect, go to **WPML->Languages->Browser language redirect.**

[image: Browser language redirect]

The default is not to redirect visitors. You can change it to redirect only if translations exist, or redirect always. If redirecting always, visitors will go to translated content when they exist or to the homepage in the other language, if translations are missing.

You get the more information by this link, https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/automatic-redirect-based-on-browser-language/

Hope! It's useful for you...

Comment: Priyanka Modi thanks for your comment! Yes I have enabled this, but for example if browser is in french language, then the website should open in English.

Comment: @Rexhep - Please clear your browser after you can try to open this link